# ERROR data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, error-handling, type-mismatch

Trying to run the following code below so when a user selects ID from Combobox then whatever field has that ID in my database it will fill in the labels in my form.

This error in the screenshot keeps on appearing. I'm new to c# programming so, some friendly assistance would be great :)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXrzI.png)

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                OleDbCommand

 command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_newsurvey WHERE ID= '" + comboBoxID.Text + "'");
            command.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", comboBoxID.SelectedIndex.ToString());
            OleDbDataReader selectreader = command.ExecuteReader();
            

            while (selectreader.Read() == true)
            {

                string name = selectreader["txtname"].ToString();
                lblname.Text = Name;

            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
```

Comment: What is the type of the `ID` column in `tbl_newsurvey`? Separately, you appear to be *trying* to use query parameters (which is good!)... but you haven't actually used the query parameter in your query - you've just put the text version.

Comment: (I'd expect the query to end in `WHERE ID=?`. We don't know enough to know whether you actually want to pass in the selected index or the selected value...)

Comment: The type of ID in tbl_newsurvey is `Number`

Comment: Im using MS Access

Comment: I dont know what i did but i changed the data type to short text and then long text to see and test. The error disappeared but whenever you click on the button, in the label it appears as the `form name`

Comment: Then when i put the data type of `ID` in `tbl_newsurvey` back to `number` the error appeared again so i think this is a database issue

Comment: Well it still looks like you're not actually using the parameter you're adding - you seem to have ignored the second half of my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you convert your ID field to varchar in your database and check if the following line is the one throwing the error? 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", comboBoxID.SelectedIndex.ToString());

Refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).